# how do i concatenate multiple pdf file in php a while loop

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

sample code - i have used fpdf and pdf merge, when i am running this code the first and last files are getting concatenated file1 and file10. I want all the files to be concatenated

```
$i=1;
include "Barcode39.php";
include 'PDFMerger/PDFMerger.php';

while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{

ob_start();
require_once('fpdf17/fpdf.php');
$pdf=new FPDF('L','mm',array(297,210));
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Line(147.5,5,147.5,205); 
$pdf->Line(149.5,5,149.5,205);
$pdf->Line(6.8,5,6.8,205); 
$pdf->Line(291,5,291,205); 
$pdf->SetLineWidth(0.3);
$pdf->Line(6.8,25,148.5-1,25);
$pdf->Line(6.8,5,148.5-1,5);
$pdf->Line(6.8,205,148.5-1,205);
$pdf->Line(149.5,5,297-6.5,5);
$pdf->Line(149.5,205,297-6.5,205);
$pdf->SetLineWidth(0.3);
$pdf->Line(149.5,25,297-6.5,25);
$pdf->Line(6.8,33,148.5-1,33);
$pdf->Line(149.5,33,297-6.5,33);
$pdf->Line(6.8,125,148.5-1,125);
$pdf->Line(149.5,125,297-6.5,125);
$pdf->Line(6.8,131,148.5-1,131);
$pdf->Line(6.8,137,148.5-1,137);
$pdf->Line(149.5,131,297-6.5,131);
$pdf->Line(149.5,137,297-6.5,137);
$file_contents = $pdf->Output($file."shipexpresslabel.pdf",'S');
$temp_file='pdf/critica_shiplabel.pdf';  
$new_file='pdf/critica_shiplabel1'.$i.'.pdf'; 
file_put_contents($new_file, $file_contents);    
$pdf = new PDFMerger;
$pdf->addPDF($temp_file, '1')
    ->addPDF($new_file, '1')
    ->merge('file',$temp_file);

ob_end_flush(); 
$i=$i+1;

}
```

Comment: I haven't used this extension before but it does make sense by looking at your code that file1 and file10 are merging "$temp_file='pdf/critica_shiplabel.pdf';  
$new_file='pdf/critica_shiplabel1'.$i.'.pdf'; " the $i is declared as 0, I assume so the $new_file string would point to file10

Comment: $i = 1; is declared in the begining.

Comment: the issue is the 2nd page is getting replace by the new files. it is not getting concatenated

Comment: $new_file='pdf/critica_shiplabel1'.$i.'.pdf';  would be parse as pdf/critica_shiplabel10.pdf if $i was 0, are you aware of this? I'm assuming you want $new_file='pdf/critica_shiplabel'.$i.'.pdf'; instead, notice I removed the 1.

Comment: if $i was 1, $new_file would be 'pdf/critica_shiplabel11.pdf', understand?

Comment: i have found  a solution for this      $pd=$ar[0]['label1'];
print_r($size);echo "<br/>";
print_r($pd);echo "<br/>";
require('fpdf_merge.php');
$merge = new FPDF_Merge();
$merge->add($pd);
for ($i=1; $i < $size ; $i++) { 

  $pdf=$ar[$i]['label1'];
  print_r($pdf);echo "<br/>";
  
  $merge->add($pdf);
  $merge->output("pdf/shipexpresslabel.pdf",'S');
}